# How do I implement search in a DevExpress ImageListbox?

Tags: c#, search, listbox, devexpress

There is a `listbox` with a around 100 values. I want to provide the user a tool in order to find and select the one they desire.

I was thinking of putting a search above the listbox. I wonder if there is something ready-made. I really don't want to reinvent wheel.

Edit: I do not want to use `LookUpEdit` because I want to show the most likely to be selected items. The search functionality would be If the user wants to select a rare item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ListBoxControl's embedded incremental searching capabilities? This feature allows an end-user to quickly locate items by typing the initial characters of the item's text. You can activate  it via the [ListBoxControl.IncrementalSearch](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_IncrementalSearchtopic) property.

ADDITION:
You can override the embedded search as you needed. This approach is demonstrated in the following thread: [Q231473 - Customising the incremental search in the ListBoxControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q231473.aspx)

Comment: nice feature. Actually I want it to be able to search within the text not by starting characters. Ex. By typing `ter` display as a result `Water`

Comment: @odyodyodys: I have updated my answer with the possible solution on custom searching.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me some hints. I've made something similar

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to switch from a listbox to a lookupedit and turn autocomplete on. It's not exactly a search but it's fast and easy to use for your user and requires zero effort on your end.

Btw, DevExpress has excellent support on their webpage. Knowledge database, support forums and you usually get an answer within a day after you post there, often with a demo solution attached.

Cheers,

Oliver

Comment: `LookUpEdit` requires the user to use the keyboard. This is something I want to avoid. They will likely have the answer right in front of them. I want them to select it with one click only. Usability is of top importance in this project.